# No “Embedded Binaries” showing in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am integrating sdk in my project that says : -  Check if mysdk.framework is added in both “Link Binary With Libraries” and “Embedded Binaries”. If not, add by clicking on the plus icon,       but there is  No  “Embedded Binaries” showing in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Check `General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content` in your project's settings:

[image]

Comment: but there is no second option is -  "Embedded Binaries"?

Comment: have you tried to change the state of your SDK from "Do Not Embed" to "Embed without signing" like on the screenshot I've posted?